# How to relay a local IP/Port, normally accessed through PuTTY using Telnet connection, to remote PC?

Tags: ip, proxy, port-forwarding, putty, telnet

Normally I have access to a local Telnet device (static IP/Port), connected via LAN/ethernet to my Windows PC. I use PuTTY to setup a Telnet terminal and send/receive and go on with the job.

Currently I have the challenge of needing to do this remotely.

- **Location A**: PC no.1 with Telnet device connected via ethernet connection (162.16.123.248:23) -> has internet connection via WiFi adapter. I know the IP address of the this PC.
- **Location B**: PC no.2 with only a internet connection via WiFi adapter. Running PuTTY. This PC will be used to communicate with the Telnet device connected to PC no.1 on location A.

How to relay the IP/Port in such a way I can use the same connection I use local with PuTTY?

Comment: Does [Describes how to use PuTTY on Windows. Installation, terminal window, configuring, generating SSH keys.](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/putty/windows) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding.

If you install an SSH server on PC1, you can then use SSH client (PuTTY) on PC2 to open an SSH connection to PC1 and forward local port on PC2 via PC1 to the device. Then you can use another instance of PuTTY on PC2 to telnet to the local forwarded port.

The pre-release version of PuTTY 0.77 should even be able to do this in one instance (using SSH proxy).

My related answer on Stack Overflow:
[How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974131/850848#29168936)